# J2ME while running app backlight never turns off

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, backlight

I'm developing a java mobile application. My problem is that while the app is running the backlight never turns off or the cellphone goes to sleep. I would like to know if there is a way to force the backlight to turn off or how to handle IDLE time to destroy the app.

Here are the specifications of my app:

- Platform: Oracle Java (TM) Platform Micro Edition SDK 3.0.5
- CLDC: 1.0, MIDP: 2.0
- Cellphone Model: Soloking T551 (chinese mobile)

Comment: Have you checked phone settings? It sounds like a phone setting. Most J2ME developers have the exact opposite problem: That the backlight DOES turn off.

Comment: Yes, i set the settings to 5 seconds but this setting does not apply while the application is running. i know this problem is the opposite to other developers but im programming in a very low end cell phone and is chinese, so i dont know any API for this mobile.